# python Occurring letters in a string. Index Counting

Tags: python

Just trying to write a basic function where the function should print index numbers of a certain letter in a word for.

Below is the function is wrote. It is only printing out the first index a the letter I give

```
def ind_fnd(word, char):
    """
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "o")
    '2 5 '
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "l")
    '3 4 '
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "n")
    ''
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "a")
    '0'
    """
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        if word [index] == char:
            return index
        index += 1
```

The above is the type of function i need. I cant figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't return the index straightaway since that terminates the function. Instead do it as follows:

```
def ind_fnd(word, char):
    """
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "o")
    '2 5 '
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "l")
    '3 4 '
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "n")
    ''
    >>> ind_fnd("apollo", "a")
    '0'
    """
    index = 0
    indices = []
    while index < len(word):
        if word [index] == char:
            indices.append(index)
        index += 1
    return indices
```

This creates a list of all the indices and then returns it.

#### Examples

```
>>> ind_fnd('apollo','o')
[2,5]

>>> ind_fnd('eevee','e')
[0,1,3,4]

>>> ind_fnd('hello, 'z')
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> def find(word,char):
          result=[]
          for index,i in enumerate(word):
            if i==char:
               result.append(index)
          return result

>>> print find("this is example string",'i')
[2, 5, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
def ind_find(s, c):
    return (i for i, x in enumerate(s) if x == c)
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(ind_find('apollo', 'o'))
[2, 5]
```

The reason your code isn't working is that you `return` once the first index is found. My code fixes this by constructing a `list` of all indices, and then returns that when applicable.